# unable to use external javascript in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, gojs

I want to use goJS with GWT. I downloaded GOJS javascript and put it in the sampleproject folder under war where sampleproject.nocache.js and sampleproject.devmode.js is present. In sampleproject.html i added

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sampleproject/go.js"> 
</script>
```

In one of the view i used

```
public static native void initGo() /*-{
    var $$ = go.GraphObject.make;
}-*/;
```

when i call this function , exception is thrown:

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (ReferenceError) @com.amazon.ops.client.OpsMenuView::initGo()([]): go is not defined.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try prefixing the js call with `$wnd.`, e.g.:

```
var $$ = $wnd.go.GraphObject.make;
```

As explained [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html), GWT runs in a nested frame and you must use `$wnd` to refer to the top level window.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you put this statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="sampleproject/go.js"> 
</script>
```

**before** `<script src="sampleproject.nocache.js">` statement.